# How to check if fwrite() works in C?

Tags: c, file, struct, io, fread

I am trying to read 256 bytes of whatever data in my input file and construct the information of them into a struct, then write that struct into my output file. Since I can't simply open and read the output file, I wonder what I should do to make sure I have sucessfully written the struct to my output file?

Comment: Can you post some code to show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Check the `fwrite()` return value looks like a good place to start.

Comment: If you write the struct to a file as is then beware of padding!

Comment: "Since I can't simply open and read the output file" - why not?

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value from `fwrite`- i.e. read manual page http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/

Comment: Were u hinting about the return value? But how can I know the data in output file is correct even I wrote the same amount of elements I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can read again the file and cast it to your struct and check it's values.

Comment: How should I cast it?

Comment: Just read the file and copy it's contents to your struct using memcpy:

myobject obj;

memcpy( &obj, file_buffer, read_byte_count);

Answer (score 0):

You've got several basic issues. Firstly, you need to verify that the data
you have read in is valid. Secondly, having constructed your data structure
in memory you need to write it out to a different file. Thirdly, you want
to guarantee that this has been written out correctly - but you don't say
what you are allowed to in order to verify the output file's correctness.

Reading the data in is easy - fread() is your friend here. I would read it
all into a (void *) of the appropriate size.

What I've done in similar data in / data out use-cases in the past is to
include a simple (depending on the application) checksum as the first element
in your output data structure. Use bcopy() or memcpy() to transfer your read-in
data to your output structure, then calculate the checksum on the data and
update the checksum field.

Finally, you fwrite() all that data to the output file, and check the return
value - the number of objects written out. If there is an error (number written
is less than desired), you need to check errno and handle the error case.
In my copy of the manual (Solaris 11.x), the error codes possible for
fwrite(3c) are those for fputc(3c).

Finally finally, you can determine whether sufficient bytes have been written
to the output file by comparing the statbut from a stat() call immediately
after opening the output file, and one immediately your fwrite() + fclose()
has returned.

Answer (score -1):

If you opened the file for reading **and** writing, you should also be able to `fseek` to the beginning (offset 0) and re-read the file from there. That's assuming you're ok with opening the file for reading and writing together.

Answer (score -1):

Check the return code as chux suggested. Open the input and output files in a hex editor and compare the first 256 bytes. Emacs has one that works well enough.

Comment: The input file is not the same as the output file